# Python HTML scraping cannot find attribute I know exists?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, tags

I am using the lxml and requests modules, and just trying to parse the article from a website. I tried using find_all from BeautifulSoup but still came up empty

```py
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/kumaraswamy-congress-leaders-meet-to-discuss-cabinet-reshuffle/article27283040.ece')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

article = tree.xpath('//div[@class="article"]/text()')
```

Once I print article, I get a list of ['\n','\n','\n','\n','\n'], rather than the body of the article. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use bs4 and the class name in css `select_one`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
page = requests.get('https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/kumaraswamy-congress-leaders-meet-to-discuss-cabinet-reshuffle/article27283040.ece')
soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.article').text)
```

If you use

```
article = tree.xpath('//div[@class="article"]//text()')
```

you get a list and still get all the \n but also the text which I think you can handle with re.sub or conditional logic.

Comment: Yes that definitely worked, now I just have the article class selected. Thank you!